# I want to see study name but it gave me numbers instead?

Tags: r, cbind

I am doing meta-analysis between 2 arms using meta package and used subset if number of events are available in all comparison arms but I got weird results (NA in some cells) then I tried to investigate the cause using the following code

```
data$Studlab<- as.factor(data$Studlab)
show<- cbind(Studlab,IMA.number.of.grafts.TOTAL, IMA.MGF.overall,IMA.MGF.overall.SD, Venous.TOTAL.number.of.grafts,     Venous.MGF.overall, Venous.MGF.overall.SD);show
```

It gave me numbers instead of authors in studlab column
[image]

Original column is as follow

[image]

My original dataset is gigantic.
Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It would be that the column is `factor` (based on the first line of code)

```
data$Studlab<- as.factor(data$Studlab)
```

we can change it to `character` and it should work  or better would be to use `data.frame` instead of `cbind` (as `cbind` returns a `matrix` and `matrix` can have only single type.  There is a strong possibility that the `factor` is coerced to integer storage mode while `cbind`ing with the rest of the columns that are just numeric).

```
data.frame(Studlab,IMA.number.of.grafts.TOTAL, IMA.MGF.overall,IMA.MGF.overall.SD, Venous.TOTAL.number.of.grafts,     Venous.MGF.overall, Venous.MGF.overall.SD)
```

Note clear whether the OP is `attach`ing the `data.frame` which would be a bad option.  There are ways to subset the columns (`with` or `$` or `[[`) instead of `attach`

Comment: Thanks . I tried `data$Studlab<- as.character(data$Studlab)` and repeated the `cbind` but did not work BUT  `show<- data.frame(Studlab,IMA.number.of.grafts.TOTAL, IMA.MGF.overall,IMA.MGF.overall.SD,
             Venous.TOTAL.number.of.grafts,     Venous.MGF.overall,   Venous.MGF.overall.SD);show` works. Appreciate.